# SharePoint Foundation Missing Document Information Panel

Tags: document, dip

All

I created a Document Content Type with an excel template and for some reason I cannot find the setting to show Document Information Panel by default. The behavior at the moment the user actually has to click new document. it opens the excel file and then it doesn't show the information panel. Then you have to try and save it before it actually allows them to see the panel. How can I have this to show on default in SharePoint Foundation 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Document Information Panel Settings is not available in SharePoint 2010 Foundation.